# Creating a 1GB file doesn't change free space on hard drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to create an empty file based on the remaining hard disk space.  The problem is that when I create a file that is 1 GB large, the df command shows the remaining space to be only 12 kb smaller than it was before the file was created.

```
someone@here:/tmp/delete# df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             36827144   5031592  29924788  15% /
tmpfs                   508508         0    508508   0% /lib/init/rw
varrun                  508508       156    508352   1% /var/run
varlock                 508508         4    508504   1% /var/lock
udev                    508508       140    508368   1% /dev
tmpfs                   508508      1108    507400   1% /dev/shm

someone@here:/tmp/delete# dd if=/dev/zero of=tempFile bs=1000 count=1 seek=1000000
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1000 bytes (1.0 kB) copied, 0.000438915 s, 2.3 MB/s

someone@here:/tmp/delete# df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             36827144   5031604  29924776  15% /
tmpfs                   508508         0    508508   0% /lib/init/rw
varrun                  508508       156    508352   1% /var/run
varlock                 508508         4    508504   1% /var/lock
udev                    508508       140    508368   1% /dev
tmpfs                   508508      1108    507400   1% /dev/shm
```

Does anyone know why the df command doesn't account for the full 1GB?  Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You created it on a filesystem that supports [sparse files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) so it actually only takes up 1000 bytes, just as the output from `dd` says. Omit `seek` and use a proper `count`.

Answer (score 3):

From [`info coreutils du`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/du-invocation.html#du-invocation) (emphasis mine):

> '--apparent-size'
>        Print apparent sizes, rather than disk usage.  The apparent size
>        of a file is the number of bytes reported by 'wc -c' on regular
>        files, or more generally, 'ls -l --block-size=1' or 'stat
>        --format=%s'.  For example, a file containing the word `zoo' with
>        no newline would, of course, have an apparent size of 3.  Such a
>        small file may require anywhere from 0 to 16 KiB or more of disk
>        space, depending on the type and configuration of the file system
>        on which the file resides.  However, a **sparse** file created with
>        **this command**:
>
> dd bs=1 seek=2GiB if=/dev/null of=big
>
> has an **apparent size of 2 GiB**, yet on most modern systems, it
>        actually **uses almost no disk space**.

Comment: Huh, sparse files. Excellent for VM images :).